# Chef server error on create user (/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist)

Tags: configuration, chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04, vps

I am extremely new to chef and I am attempting to create a chef server running on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 droplet. I am using [this guide](https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html) for the install. I download the .deb and installed it fine. I then run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` which runs without an issue. When I go to create my user I enter in all the details and run it, it then waits a few seconds and returns the error `ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist`

I have scoured the internet to try and find a fix but haven't been able to find a thing. I have also tried doing these exact steps on a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04.5 and getting identical results.

Answer (score 8):

For /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem is missing error use following command.

cp /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/spec/fixtures/pivotal.pem  /etc/opscode/

Comment: done this now it's saying /etc/chef/client.pem missing

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same thing when trying to install chef in an VM.

Expanding the memory (from 512Mb to 1512Mb) and reran reconfigure solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. An older version, for example 12.03 of chef-server works for me with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Or try to create the file  with something like this:
node_name "pivotal"
chef_server_url "https://127.0.0.1:443"
chef_server_root "https://127.0.0.1:443"
client_key "/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem"

Comment: Tried to install 12.08 - failed with same error. Installing 12.03 solved problem

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` had a syntax error.

The syntax error was displayed earlier in the logs, however my install script has kept going, causing later on this error.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you have forgotten to run `chef-server-ctl` reconfigure. It's ambiguous naming of the command as it's **re**configure, however the [installation guide](https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html) for Chef Server actually states to run it after installing the package.

Why it's not part of the installation process is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  I exited my ssh session to the node I was configuring.  I connected again and ran `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` again.  I was able to then create a user without the error.  I was using *chef-server-core_12.1.0-1_amd64.deb* for my install.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Ubuntu  trusty 14.04 64 bit

**/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb** does not exist. I followed what **Matthias** Said and destroyed my VM ( I'm using  Vagrant), then I quickly set up the VM and installed Chef server 12.03. I can now set up users correctly.

Just an FYI I also tried to install the latest version of chef which is 12.2.0 and do this but I also ran into the same error when trying to provision a user account.

Downgrading to 12.03 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I run in the same issue on CentOS 7 and Chef Infra Server 12.19.31; the following steps helped me to get the root cause of the problem.

1. Re-run the chef-server-ctl reconfigure and check if it gives any error at the end of the run

In my case, I received the error
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 minutes 19 seconds

2. Check the stack trace / output log on 
   /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/chef-stacktrace.out
   I received 
   Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - ls -1 /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_id/db/migrate | tail -n 1 | sed -e "s/_.*//g"

To solve the problem, I upgraded the system with higher memory.

**TL;DR;**

1. Rerun the chef-server-ctl reconfigure to get the error
2. Upgrade the allocated memory to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Me too got this error while installing chef infra server pkg in centos 8.
"ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR: Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist"

Post Memory up-gradation I re-run below cmd its fixed issue:
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure

Comment: This is not an answer to the original post.